# Existe algum método que retorne informações sobre o smartphone?

Tags: java, android

Desejo obter informações como a versão do Android e modelo do aparelho, o método `System.getProperties()` me retorna as propriedades do App.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que juntando duas classes você consegue obter um grande número de propriedades.

## android.os.Build

> **VERSION.SDK_INT**: Versão da API em numero absoluto (10, 11, 22...).
>
> **BOARD**: O nome da placa interna, por exemplo "goldfish".
>
> **BOOTLOADER**: O número de versão do bootloader do sistema.
>
> **BRAND**: A marca visível ao consumidor associada ao produto, caso haja.
>
> **CPU_ABI**: Campo "em desuso" na API 21. Ao invés use SUPPORTED_ABIS.
>
> **CPU_ABI2**: Campo "em desuso" na API 21. Ao invés use SUPPORTED_ABIS.
>
> **DEVICE**: Nome do design industrial.
>
> **DISPLAY**: String representativa ao usuário sobre o ID do *build*.
>
> **FINGERPRINT**: Uma String que representa unicamente o *build*.
>
> **HARDWARE**: Nome do hardware (da linha de comando do kernel ou do /proc).
>
> **HOST**: Sem documentação
>
> **ID**: Ou um número de *changelist* ou um label como"M4-rc20".
>
> **MANUFACTURER**: O fabricante do produto/hardware.
>
> **MODEL**: O nome do produto visível ao usuário final.
>
> **PRODUCT**: O nome geral do produto.
>
> **RADIO**: Campo em "desuso" na API 14. Versão do firmware de radio, que frequentemente é deixando em branco ou com valor "unknown". Ao invés use getRadioVersion().
>
> **SERIAL**: Um número de serial do hardware , se disponível.
>
> **SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS**: Uma lista ordenada de 32 bits ABIs suportada pelo dispositivo.
>
> **SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS**: Uma lista ordenada de 64 bits ABIs suportada pelo dispositivo.
>
> **SUPPORTED_ABIS**: Uma lista ordenada de ABIs suportada pelo dispositivo.
>
> **TAGS**: Uma lista de tags separadas por ponto-e-vírgula descrevendo o *build*, como "unsigned,debug".
>
> **TIME**: Sem documentação
>
> **TYPE**: O tipo de *build*, como "user" ou "eng".
>
> **USER**: Sem documentação

## android.content.res.Configuration

> **densityDpi**: A densidade da tela, usado para selecionar (através dos qualificadores de densidade) os *resources* usados.
>
> **fontScale**: A preferência corrente do usuário para o fator de escala de fontes, relativas a base de densidade.
>
> **hardKeyboardHidden**: Uma flag indicando se o menu físico está escondido.
>
> **keyboard**: O tipo de teclado ligado ao dispositivo.
>
> **keyboardHidden**: Uma flag indicando se algum teclado está disponível.
>
> **locale**: O locale do usuário, usado para selecionar recursos, através dos qualificadores.
>
> **mcc**: IMSI MCC (Mobile Country Code), correspondente ao qualificador de recursos mcc.
>
> **mnc**: IMSI MNC (Mobile Network Code), correspondente ao qualificador de recurso mnc.
>
> **navigation**: O tipo de método de navegação usada no dispositivo.
>
> **navigationHidden**: Uma flag indicando se alguma navegação *5-way* ou *DPAD* está disponível.
>
> **orientation**: Orientação geral da tela.
>
> **screenHeightDp**: A altura de tela disponível, em unidade *dp*, correspondente ao qualificador de recurso de altura (hdp).
>
> **screenLayout**: Um bit de máscara do layout geral da tela.
>
> **screenWidthDp**: A largura de tela disponível, em unidade *dp*, correspondente ao qualificador de recurso de altura (wdp).
>
> **smallestScreenWidthDp**: A menor largura de tela que a aplicação irá ter em uma operação normal. Corresponde ao qualificador de menor largura de tela (swdp).
>
> **touchscreen**: O tipo de *touchscreen* ligado ao dispositivo.
>
> **uiMode**: Bit de máscara do *ui mode*.

Para os casos dos qualificadores, uma boa referência seria: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

---

Existem algumas bibliotecas que reportam erros, e eles usam algumas dessas propriedades para enviar ao desenvolvedor.

No caso do [**ACRA**](https://github.com/ACRA/acra), acho legal dar uma olhada no código para ter uma inspiração (classe [`CrashReportDataFactory`](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/blob/master/src/main/java/org/acra/collector/CrashReportDataFactory.java)), já que ele busca outras propriedades que não estão nessa lista e as vezes é interessante saber.

Referências:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html